# Cant use OME in Outlook for Mac

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I am using Office 365 with Outlook for Mac 16.29 on 10.14.6.

In OWA I can use [Office 365 Message Encryption (OME)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/email-encryption) but in Outlook the option is greyed out. On the other hand, my colleague can use it in Outlook and OWA and I can ready OME Mails, so it is not a limitation of the Mac app.

How do I get OME working in Outlook for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

What’s the version of Outlook for Mac? According to the official article, the Encrypt-Only feature (the option under the Encrypt button) is only enabled for subscribers (Office ProPlus users) that also use Exchange Online.

Please check this article: [Send a digitally signed or encrypted message](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-a-digitally-signed-or-encrypted-message-a18ecf7f-a7ac-4edd-b02e-687b05eff547?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

If license has no problem, we can  [create a new profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-profiles-or-identities-in-outlook-for-mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c) to test the results.